# Получение тэга <img> и последующее его удаление из текста

Tags: android

Необходимо сначала найти тэг  (со всеми его атрибутами) в тексте HTML, а потом полностью его удалить именно этот тэг (со всем его содержимым и атрибутами).

Как найти, можно посмотреть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545370/extract-image-src-from-imgtag-in-android)

```
String html = "<img SRC=\"whatever\">whatever</img>"
    String imgRegex = "<[iI][mM][gG][^>]+[sS][rR][cC]\\s*=\\s*['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"][^>]*>";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(imgRegex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(html);

    if (m.find()) {
        String imgSrc = m.group(1);
    }
```

А вот как потом удалить найденный тэг со всем его содержимым?

Comment: Нашел ответ [тут] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178533/how-to-skip-image-tag-in-html-data-in-android). Но пока не понял, как изменить регулярное выражение, чтобы удалять конкретный тэг. Понимаю, что уникальным идентификатором может являться ссылка ... как ее добавить в выражение `String htmlBody = htmlString.replaceAll("(<(/)img>)|(<img.+?>)", "");` ?

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/), без проблем решает эту задачу.